# Entity framework Identity add foreign key to (and from) AspNetUsers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to add a foreign key from "AspNetUsers" table (generated by identity entity framework) to a table "Clients" (generated by my own class using code first entity framework) in order to make a one-to-one relationship.

I don't know how to reference from Clients to AspNetUsers (because that is not a class in my models).

Here is my code, first my client model:

```
namespace TransportNEA.Models
{
    public class Client
    {
        [Key]
        public int ClientID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public virtual List<ClientAddress> Address { get; set; }

        //I want to add here a FOREIGN KEY to AspNetUsers table but I don't know how
    }
}
```

My context:

```
namespace TransportNEA.Context
{
    public class TNEAContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The register view model from AccountViewModels class:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Apellido")]
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Telefono")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Correo electrónico")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "El número de caracteres de {0} debe ser al menos {2}.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Contraseña")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirmar contraseña")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "La contraseña y la contraseña de confirmación no coinciden.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int ClientID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ClientID")]
        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    }
```

And finally the IdentityModels class:

```
namespace TransportNEA.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [Required]
        public int ClientID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ClientID")]
        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("IdentityConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

I am tired of trying to solve this by myself, can somebody tell me what do I need to modify or add in order to make it work?
Also as you can see when I make an entry in AspNetUsers I want to create an entry in Clients  and have them associated

PS: I have to use migrations in order to make the project work
(because I am getting an error with a constraint that might be causing
"double relation" and I need to set "on delete no action" instead of
cascade but I don't know how to use fluent API that's why I use
migrations. And to generate the database I'm using my context
TNEAContext (not the ApplicationDbContext)

Comment: Doesn't your context inherit from `IdentityDbContext<>`?

Comment: No it doesn't, it inherits from DbContext. Do I need to make it inherit from IdentityDbContext<> ?

Comment: I didn't notice that you have 2 context classes here. Is that intentional? Why not just use the `ApplicationDbContext` class and put your `DbSet<Client> Clients` in there?

Comment: @DavidG Ok, I tried to do that but now when registering I get this error `Error de validación para una o varias entidades. Vea la propiedad 'EntityValidationErrors' para obtener más detalles.` which means something like this  `Error validating one or more entities. To get more details look up to the property 'EntityValidationErrors'`